# How Should I Add Authorisation In My REST API If I Use Azure APIM?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-api-management

I am planning on hosting my REST API in a VM in a VNET where the only point of entry is via Azure API Management.

I have multiple back ends so the API Management will route to a different backend base url depending on the group the user is in and the backend will also return different data depending on the user making the call.

Since the Azure API Management can handle authorisation, JWT validation and setting headers etc what type of authorisation code should I put in my REST API application?

Should I try to validate the JWT again in my Java code or just parse the headers?

i.e. is it safe to code it as a public API and trust that the headers have been set correctly by API Management?

Or should I make a call to Azure Active Directory from the Spring controller every time to validate that the user does actually exist in the specified group and that the group specified is the one expected for this backend?

If so, how would I do that from Java and how would I inject an offline version when running locally?

Comment: Opinionated question. Need? No. But it is still a Very Good Idea to implement security principles across the entire request chain for the corner cases such as limiting exposure when somebody actually manages to break in.

Comment: Reworded it to be less opinionated and more about how/what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since your API will be inside a VNET it'll be protected as it is. But, there is really no reason to just have it open. The more layers of protection you can add the better your chances to whistand a potential attack.

So see whatever is most convenient to you. You can rely on APIM doing user authentication and authorization and avoid doing that in your backend API. But it would be a good idea to check if call made to your backend API is coming from APIM, and you can do that by sending credentials from APIM. The best option here would be client certificates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates

But you can also send basic credentials: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#Basic